# Recursively check ownership of all files

Tags: linux, bash

This if my first attempt at bash scripting.  I am trying to create a script to check on every single file owner and group starting under a certain directory.

For example if I have this:

```
files=/*  
for f in $files; do  
    owner=$(stat -c %U $f)  
    if [ "$owner" != "someone"  ]; then  
        echo $f $owner  
    fi  
done
```

The ultimate goal is to fix permission problems.  However, I am not able to get the `/*` variable to go underneath everything in `/`, it will only check the files under `/` and stop at any new directories.  Any pointers on how I could check for permissions over everything under `/` and any of its sub-directories?

Comment: Hi! Shall this work recursively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this one, it is a recursive one:

```
function playFiles {
    files=$1
    for f in $files; do
            if [ ! -d $f ]; then
                    owner=$(stat -c %U $f)
                    echo "Simple FILE=$f  -- OWNER=$owner"
                    if [ "$owner" != "root"  ]; then
                            echo $f $owner
                    fi
            else
                    playFiles "$f/*"
            fi
    done
}
playFiles "/root/*"
```

Play a little with in a another directory before replacing playFiles "/root/*" with : playFiles "/*". Btw playFiles is a bash function. Hopefully this will help  you.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I liked the function better and it works just fine.

Comment: for unix users, change owner line to `owner=$(stat -f %Su $f)`

Comment: quick question, why does this script print out the $f/* value?

Answer (score 32):

You can `shopt -s globstar` and use `for f in yourdir/**` to expand recursively in bash4+, or you can use `find`:

```
find yourdir ! -user someone
```

If you want the same output format with username and filename, you have to get system specific:

```
GNU$  find yourdir ! -user someone -printf '%p %u\n' 
OSX$  find yourdir ! -user someone -exec stat -f '%N %Su' {} +
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer. For osx users, `brew install findutils`  and use `gfind` without pains.

Answer (score 9):

List all files recursively in list format and hidden files which shows ownership and permissions

```
ls -Rla *
```